# Java pattern to find two groups of two letters in `ABC`

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern defined like this:

```
 private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{2}");
```

And in my code I'm doing this:

```
 Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(myString);
```

and using a while loop to find all matches.

```
 while (matcher.find()){
 //do something here
 }
```

If `myString` is `12345AB3CD45` the matcher is finding those two groups of two letters (`AB` and `CD`). The problem is that I have sometimes `myString` as `12345ABC356` so I would like the matcher to find, first `AB` and then `BC` (is only finding `AB).

Am I doing this wrong or the regex is wrong or the matcher doesn't work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment of text which was placed in group 0 (entire match) can't be reused in next match to be part of group 0.

```
12345ABC356
     ^^  - AB was placed in standard match (group 0)
      ^^ - B can't be reused here as part of standard match
```

You can solve this problem with look-around mechanisms like [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead), which doesn't *consume* matched part (they are zero-length), but you can place their content in separate [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which you will be able to access.

So your code can look like

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z](?=([a-zA-Z]))");
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                       group 0    group 1

//...

Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(myString);
while (matcher.find()){
    String match = matcher.group() + matcher.group(1);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With your implementation I've managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't match a same position several times with a regex, but you can use a trick.

To do that you need to enclose your pattern in a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a capture group:

`(?=([A-Za-z]{2}))`, because a lookahead matches no characters and consumes only one position.

The result you are looking for is in the capture group 1.