# Regex: matching two times if the second matchbegins with the end of the first match

Tags: regex, match

I need to match a specifi string 2 times but if I match the first one I can't match the second one because a part of the first match is the beginning of the second match I need.

Example:

```
radaradarr
```

first match: `radar`
second match: `radarr`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Same problem than this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003443/java-pattern-to-find-two-groups-of-two-letters-in-abc

Comment: You can't do that in pure regex. You will need some code around it to handle calculating offsets.